# I am unable to get menulist options into arraylist

Tags: selenium-webdriver

HTML Code:

```
<td width="50%">
<div id="divselect-tab" style="width:100%;">
<div id="s2id_select-tab" class="select2-container FontFace" style="width:100%;">
<a class="select2-choice select2-default" href="javascript:void(0)" tabindex="-1">
<span id="select2-chosen-1" class="select2-chosen"/>
<abbr class="select2-search-choice-clos**`strong text`**e"/>
<span class="select2-arrow" role="presentation">
</a>
```

I got the exception:

> Element should have been "select" but was "a".

Comment: And the code giving the error?

Comment: Select sel=new Select(branchPL);
  List<WebElement> Adminoptions = sel.getOptions();
  for(int size=0;size<Adminoptions.size();size++)
  {
   String itemname=Adminoptions.get(size).getText();
   System.out.println("ItemName: "+itemname);
   sel.selectByVisibleText("ADDRESS-Y");
   Thread.sleep(1000);
  }

Comment: This web driver code is giving exception:UnexpectedTagnameException.